# C++ Send a variable List of type ref class to a native class

Tags: class, c++-cli

I basic have the following code.

```
//*** Field.h ***\\
public ref class Field
{
public:
    String^ Name;
    UInt16 Lenght;
    Field(void);
}

//*** SNVT.h ***\\
public ref class SNVT
{
public:
    String^ Name;
    UInt16 Index;
    List<Field^> FieldList;
    SNVT(void);
}

//*** Viewer.h ***\\
public ref class Viewer
{
public:
    List<SNVT^> SNVT_List;
    Viewer(void);
    SomeViewerFunction();
}

//*** Viewer.cpp ***\\
void SomeViewerFunction()
{
SNVT^ currentSNVT = gcnew SNVT();
Field^ currentField = gcnew Field();
currentField->Name = "Field Name";
currentField->Leght = 10;

currentSNVT->Name = "SNVT Name";
currentSNVT->Index = 1;
currentSNVT->FieldList.Add(currentField);

SNVT_List.Add(currentSNVT);

Tools New_Tools;
New_Tools.SomeToolsFunction(SNVT_List);
}

//*** Tools.h ***\\
class Tools
{
public:
    Tools(void);
    SomeToolsFunction(List<SNVT^> Tools_SNVT_List);
}

//*** Tools.cpp ***\\
void SomeToolsFunction(List<SNVT^> Tools_SNVT_List)
{
/*
use Tools_SNVT_List here
*/
}
```

So the idea is that I would call SomeViewerFunction, which will add data to SNVT_List. Then SomeViewerFunction will create an instance of Tools, to call SomeToolsFunction. SomeToolsFunction takes the variable SNVT_List.

But I get an error; class "System::Collections::Generic::List" has no suitable copy constructor.

At the end of the day, all I would like to achieve is the create a System::Collections::Generic::List type variable of type SNVT in the Viewer and then, send that variable to Tools. 
Any idea on how I can achieve this?

Please note the following...
All my classes are ref classes, except class Tools. Class Tools has to stay a native class. 
I know this would be easier in C#, but someone else started this project in C++, so I have to continue in c++;

// 2019-01-10
Thank you David Yaw
I changed the code to the following, and it works as I expected.

```
//*** Field.h ***\\
public ref class Field
{
public:
    String^ Name;
    UInt16 Lenght;
    Field(void);
}

//*** SNVT.h ***\\
public ref class SNVT
{
public:
    String^ Name;
    UInt16 Index;
    List<Field^> FieldList;
    SNVT(void);
}

//*** Viewer.h ***\\
public ref class Viewer
{
public:
    List<SNVT^>^ SNVT_List; // I changed this line from List<SNVT^> SNVT_List;
    Viewer(void);
    SomeViewerFunction();
}

//*** Viewer.cpp ***\\
void SomeViewerFunction()
{
    SNVT_List = gcnew List<SNVT^>(); // I added this line

    SNVT^ currentSNVT = gcnew SNVT();
    Field^ currentField = gcnew Field();
    currentField->Name = "Field Name";
    currentField->Leght = 10;

    currentSNVT->Name = "SNVT Name";
    currentSNVT->Index = 1;
    currentSNVT->FieldList.Add(currentField);

    SNVT_List->Add(currentSNVT); // I changed this line from SNVT_List.Add(currentSNVT);

    Tools New_Tools;
    New_Tools.SomeToolsFunction(SNVT_List);
}

//*** Tools.h ***\\
class Tools
{
public:
    Tools(void);
    SomeToolsFunction(List<SNVT^>^ Tools_SNVT_List); // I changed this line from SomeToolsFunction(List<SNVT^> Tools_SNVT_List); 
}

//*** Tools.cpp ***\\
void SomeToolsFunction(List<SNVT^>^ Tools_SNVT_List) // I changed this line from void SomeToolsFunction(List<SNVT^> Tools_SNVT_List)
{
/*
use Tools_SNVT_List here
*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Whatever^> Foo
```

This type is improper, almost always. Whether it's a class member, a method parameter, or a local variable, switch it to `List<Whatever^>^ Foo`, with the second `^`. Initialize it with `gcnew List<Whatever^>()`. (Note: If it's a list of a value type, such as `int`, no `^` inside the `<>`.)

List is a reference type (`class` in C#, `ref class` in C++/CLI). Therefore it should always be a reference to an object on the managed heap, which is what `^` means.

Without the `^`, the reference type gets put onto the stack/allocated directly within the object, which is possible in C++/CLI, but isn't possible in C#. Therefore, none of the APIs are expecting that type. That's why you're getting the "List has no suitable copy constructor" error, because you're trying to use `List<Whatever^>`, but the copy constructor takes a `List<Whatever^>^`.

Also, note that this is *not* C++. This is C++/CLI, which has all the complexities of C++, all the complexities of C#, and a few of its own.

Comment: Thank you David Yaw
Another question that I have that I don't understand. 
Why can't I have a List<SNVT^>^ SNVT_List in the Tools class, or a global List<SNVT^>^ SNVT_List in the Tools.cpp file?

Comment: Your `Tools` class is a C++ **native** code, while  `List<SNVT^>^` is an object from different world - **managed** world of .NET Framework. The great C++/CLI was created to easily deal with both worlds. Thus, in your managed `ref` C++/CLI classes you can combine both native and managed code but in native `Tools` class it is not that easy to deal with managed objects.